# What is the most efficient/optimal way to simplify the given function? Does the given code need more assumptions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

I have a very long function for $\{x,b\}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$; here, I have only mentioned a short part of that. The function is a sum of the complex exponentials (a picture is attached below).

I want to simplify such a function in the shortest and simplest form possible; I am somehow sure that there should be a multiplicative factor $i$ in the whole function.

**My question**

> What is the most efficient/optimal way to simplify the given function? Does the code  `exp // ExpandAll // ExpToTrig // TrigExpand // TrigFactor //  Simplify[#,  Assumptions -> x > 0 && x \[Element] Reals  && b \[Element] Reals  && n \[Element] Integers && 0 < n < 11 ] &` do the job for me? Since the function is too long, I am afraid of using `FullSimplify` due to timing. In particular, is the assumption $0 < n < 11$ sufficient (since $n=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ only)?

I appreciate any comments.

```
exp := -462 E^( 9 I b + (2 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    20 I x) (10 + E^((2 I n \[Pi])/11) + E^((14 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     10 E^((16 I n \[Pi])/11) + 7 E^((18 I n \[Pi])/11)) (-1 + E^(
     2 I x)) + 
  66 E^((2 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    9 I (b + 2 x)) (-3 + 5 E^((2 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     5 E^((14 I n \[Pi])/11) - 3 E^((16 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     9 E^((18 I n \[Pi])/11)) (-1 + E^(6 I x)) + 
  55 E^(9 I b + (2 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    16 I x) (7 - 3 E^((2 I n \[Pi])/11) - 3 E^((14 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     7 E^((16 I n \[Pi])/11) + 31 E^((18 I n \[Pi])/11)) (-1 + E^(
     10 I x)) - 
  E^(9 I b + (2 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    14 I x) (319 - 55 E^((2 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     4749 E^((4 I n \[Pi])/11) + 4749 E^((12 I n \[Pi])/11) - 
     55 E^((14 I n \[Pi])/11) + 319 E^((16 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     1903 E^((18 I n \[Pi])/11)) (-1 + E^(14 I x)) + 
  E^(11 I b + (2 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    12 I x) (963 + 147 E^((2 I n \[Pi])/11) - 
     11 E^((4 I n \[Pi])/11) - 11 E^((16 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     147 E^((18 I n \[Pi])/11)) (-1 + E^(18 I x)) - 
  E^(9 I b + (2 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    10 I x) (37 - E^((2 I n \[Pi])/11) - E^((14 I n \[Pi])/11) + 
     37 E^((16 I n \[Pi])/11) + 253 E^((18 I n \[Pi])/11)) (-1 + E^(
     22 I x)) - 
  528 E^(12 I b + (13 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    19 I x)  (5 Cos[(n \[Pi])/11] + Cos[(3 n \[Pi])/11]) (-1 + E^(
     4 I x)) - 
  528 E^(10 I b + I n \[Pi] + 
    19 I x)  (3 Cos[(n \[Pi])/11] + 2 Cos[(3 n \[Pi])/11] + 
     Cos[(5 n \[Pi])/11]) (-1 + E^(16 I x)) - 
  E^(11 I b + (2 I n \[Pi])/11 + 
    14 I x) (1903 + 
     2 E^((10 I n \[Pi])/
      11) (4749 Cos[(4 n \[Pi])/11] - 55 Cos[(6 n \[Pi])/11] + 
        319 Cos[(8 n \[Pi])/11])) (-1 + E^(14 I x))
```

[image]

Comment: Link to [OP's closely related previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275718/is-there-any-hope-to-significantly-simplify-the-given-function-make-it-shortene).

Comment: @user293787 It is not related; I have used the code there to simplify my function, and now, I have another obstacle.

Comment: This function has period $2\pi$ in the real number $x$, period $2\pi$ in the real number $b$, and period $11$ in the integer $n$. One can write it as a Fourier series in $x$, Fourier series in $b$, discrete Fourier series in $n$, which is roughly what you have after `TrigToExp`. That is a natural way of writing it, because the Fourier basis is linearly independent. I guess more simplifications are possible in principle, maybe one can `Factor` somehow, but it would seem that such further simplifications depend on knowing all terms, not just the selection that you have given.

Comment: @user293787 Thanks. Is my assumption for $n$ correct? Since the result is different for $0$ and multiples of $11$, then, is this $0<n<11$ sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using new variables `t,u,v` as follows:

```
e1 = TrigToExp[TrigToExp[exp] /. {n->11*Log[t]/(Pi*I)}
   //ExpToTrig //Simplify] /. {x->Log[u]/I, b->Log[v]/I};
e2 = e1/(t^2*v^9*(1-u^2)*u^10) //Factor //FullSimplify;
```

You can check the result with the original with, for example:

```
N[{exp, e2*(t^2*v^9*(1-u^2)*u^10)} /. 
  {t->E^(Pi*I*n/11), v->E^(b*I), u->E^(x*I)} /.
  {x->3/10*I, b->2/13*I, n->5/7}, 50]
```

The timing is not long with this approach. The test of if the
result is "simpler" than the original is up to you. The `e2` is
a polynomial in `t,u,v` with integer coefficients.